# Check if string is in the BMP range

Tags: php, unicode, astral-plane

So I was searching for a proper way in PHP to detect if a string is in the BMP range ([Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)) but I found nothing. Even [mb-check-encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) and [mb_detect_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) do not offer any help in this particular case.

So I wrote my own code

```
<?php

function is_bmp($string) {
    $str_ar = mb_str_split($string);
    foreach ($str_ar as $char) {
        /*Check if there's any character's code point outside the BMP range*/
        if (mb_ord($char) > 0xFFFF)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/*String containing non-BMP Unicode characters*/
$string = 'blah blah';
var_dump(is_bmp($string));
?>
```

**Outputs:**

bool(false)

**Now my question is:**

Is there a better approach? and are there any flaws in it?

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but I am curious what is the use case for this?

Comment: @Dharman Well, in MySQL utf8 charset doesn't map to the UTF-8 encoding. It only partially implements it making symbols that take up four bytes not supported. Therefore, inserting non-BMP data can result in security vulnerabilities. So i thought i can find a way to detect those unsupported symbols without using utf8mb4.

Comment: If I can give you a word of advice: don't try to fix symptoms fix the root cause. The old `utf8` should not be used anymore. I know it can be very difficult to convert your whole DB, but it is worth the effort. Trying to restrict the characters one by one will slow down your application and it will never be 100% right. 

Comment: I don't think you can insert non-BMP data in MySQL's `utf8`: the query crashes with the infamous *Incorrect string value* error.

Comment: @Dharman You're right, but there are many applications where the need of those symbols (non-BMP) is not necessary! so IMHO it doesn't make any sense to use utf8mb4 over utf8 and sacrifice storage space for nothing!.

Comment: Don't worry about storage space, it is really not that expensive. Sacrificing storage space in exchange for speed and security of your application is definitely a win.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an correct UTF-8 encoded input string, you can just check its bytes to figure out does it have symbols out of BMP or not.

Literally, you need to detect: does the input string contains any symbol, which codepoint is greater than 0xFFFF (i.e. longer than 16 bits)

Note on [how UTF-8 encoding works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

- Codepoints with codes **0** thru **0x7F** are encoded as is. By one byte.
- All other codepoints have a code within range **0xC0 ... 0xFF** as the first byte, which also encodes how many additional bytes folows. And codes **0x80...0xBF** as additional bytes.

To encode code points 0x10000 and greater, UTF-8 requires a sequence of 4 bytes, and the first byte of that sequence will be **0xF0** or greater. In all other cases the whole string will contain bytes less than 0xF0.

In short your task just to find: *does the binary representation of the string contanin any byte of range 0xF0...0xFF?*

```
function is_bmp($string) {
   return preg_match('#[\xF0-\xFF]#', $string) != 0;
}
```

**OR**

even simpler (but probably less effective on speed), you can use ability of PCRE to work with UTF-8 sequences ([see option PCRE_UTF8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)):

```
function is_bmp($string) {
   return preg_match('#[^\x00-\x{FFFF}]#u', $string) != 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the regex must be `#[^\u{1}-\u{FFFF}]#u` instead. 1. starting from 1 because PCRE does not like 0-bytes, 2. using `\u` instead of `\x` because we want unicode characters and not bytes. It even seems that `\x{1234}` is invalid.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly  `\u` is an incorrect syntax. Hexadecimal codepoints in php  should be given as in the example as `\xAB` or `\x{ABCD}` (in UTF-8 mode). https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was using `"` quotes instead, so it was interpreted by PHP, that's why I had the different behavior. It seems that in UTF-8 mode you can also use `\u{1234}` in combination with double quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump(
    !preg_match('/[^\x0-\x{ffff}]/u', 'blah blah')
);
```